# Flutter: Firebase google sign-in persistent causing an automatic reauthentication

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Flutter application that utilizes Firebase and Google Sign-In for user authentication. My problem arises when I attempt to log the user out using the following code:

```
Future.wait([
  googleSignIn.currentUser!.clearAuthCache(),
  googleSignIn.disconnect(),
  googleSignIn.signOut(),
  firebaseAuth.signOut(),
]);
```

Despite executing these steps to log out, the user continues to be automatically authenticated with the last user who logged in. This is not the desired behavior, as I expect that after logging out, the user should have to select an account again and re-authenticate.

Has anyone encountered this issue before or have any ideas on how to resolve it? I appreciate any advice or suggestions for addressing this unwanted automatic authentication.

**This happens on my physical device with Android operating system in both modes, release and debug**

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but try to call methods one by one:

```dart
await googleSignIn.currentUser!.clearAuthCache();
await googleSignIn.disconnect();
await googleSignIn.signOut();

await firebaseAuth.signOut();
```

Comment: It does not work